# Bypass broken form validation in browser?

Tags: validation, webforms

I need to get to a page that's protected by a "give us some information about you" form. Fair enough, I want something from them, they want something in return. I agree to the deal.

...unfortunately their form validation is broken. (I've looked up the company's Contact Us page and sent them a message about the problem. Presumably someone will get back to me, eventually. We're a paying customer so a response will be soonish, perhaps.)

I'm impatient. Someone is waiting for me to download, install, and configure this software and license server so they can do their work. I want to get this out of the way so I can do my main work.

How might I use Firebug or Fiddler or Web Developer tools or whatever to pat the hand of the well-meaning but inexperienced teenager guarding the door with a "that's all right son, they know me, you can open the door" and get an "uhhh, okay sir" ...?

I work on Windows 7 and have current versions of Firefox, Chrome and IE at my disposal. I'm not averse to using curl or something from the command line if that'll get me where I'm going.

If it's necessary, the form in question can be deduced and found from the company name in the footer of the screen capture. However I'm taking the time to write this up because the scenario is not really website or company specific. I've run into it a number of times in a variety of circumstances and would like a general DIY hack or strategy that could be brought to bear.

[image: Screencap of filled out but rejected form]

Comment: You can probably just save the page to a file, edit the file, and then open the file with your browser. You may need to add a `<BASE>` tag.

Comment: You may want to try Tamper Data for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tamper-chrome-extension/hifhgpdkfodlpnlmlnmhchnkepplebkb?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

There are usually two types of form validation.

The first type is "basic" validation, which uses built-in HTML form validation capability, such as the `required` attribute on an `<input>`. To bypass this, you can just modify the HTML of the form to remove the validation stuffs.

The second type is more advanced, which uses JavaScript to handle complex validation logic on the form (for example, using a regex to match a phone number). If you want to bypass this, you would need to find out exactly where this validation happens, which script is responsible for it, and either disable it or modify its logic.